# How do I open the angular-ui datepicker from a button?

Tags: datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to have a calendar icon next to my input and when I click on that icon it should open the datepicker.

How to do?

Answer (score 4):

Still thinking in jQuery terms, eh?

Well, you can't "delegate" a click in angular, but you can use `angular-ui-bootsrap`'s `is-open` attribute to specify a model to bind to, such as `$scope.calendarOpened`.

```
<input ui-date type='text' ng-model="question.answer" is-open="calendarOpened" ui-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">

<button type="button" ng-click="calendarOpened = !!calendarOpened" class="btn"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
```

Tada!